# clientY is not displaying the right thing

Tags: javascript, html

I know that the title seems a bit weird, but i'm trying to create a drawing app. I have a javascript generated table that is 17 by 36 and I am trying to make it so that whenever you click in a box it colors it black. Below is the code (here it acts weirder because they are not 30 by 30 pixels)

```js
var array = [];
var body = document.body, tbl = document.createElement("table");
tbl.style.border = "1px solid black";
tbl.style.borderCollapse = "collapse";
tbl.setAttribute("border", "1px");
tbl.style.margin = "0px";
tbl.setAttribute("onClick", "color(event)");
var id = 1;
for (var j = 0; j < 17; j++) {
 var row = tbl.insertRow();
 row.setAttribute("id", id.toString());
 id++;
 for (var ij = 0; ij < 36; ij++) {
  var cell = row.insertCell();
  cell.style.width = "28px";
  cell.style.height = "28px";
 }
}
body.appendChild(tbl);


function color(event) {
 var x = event.clientX;
 var y = event.clientY;
 console.log(x + " = x");
 console.log(y + " = y");
 console.log((x/30) + " = x/30");
 console.log((y/30) + " = y/30");
 x = Math.ceil(x / 30);
 y = Math.ceil(y / 30);
 if (x == 37) {x = 36}
 if (y == 18) {y = 17}
 console.log(x + "x after");
 console.log(y + "y after");
 document.getElementById(y.toString()).childNodes[x - 1].style.background = "black";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Program</title>
  <style>
   body {
    margin: 0px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script src="program.js"></script>
  <button onClick="calculate()"></button>
 </body>
</html>
```

When I click a square in the 10th row, it colors it black. When I click it in a row near the bottom, starting from the 13th row, it goes 5 squares up. Also, if I click in the second half of a square (from the left or from the top) it thinks it's the next square over! Please help!

Comment: try event.pageX && event.pageY

Comment: the event object will contain a link to the TD that was clicked, you don't need to search for it. if you want to search, mind the padding, border, and spacing of the cells when calculating offsets...

Comment: Also, you're not setting the size of the table, didn't you notice that the "pixels" aren't really square? And the table doesn't start from the top of the page, there's a checkbox before it. So you need to subtract the table position from your calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in a comment, you are making this problem more complicated than it actually is. When you click an element, it generates a click event which contains a reference to the element that the event is for. In your case it already references the td-element that you want to change.

So: Simply use `event.target` and you are good to go.

```js
/* Creating the table */
var array = [];
var body = document.body,
    tbl = document.createElement("table");
tbl.style.border = "1px solid black";
tbl.style.borderCollapse = "collapse";
tbl.setAttribute("border", "1px");
tbl.style.margin = "0px";
tbl.setAttribute("onClick", "color(event)");
var id = 1;
for (var j = 0; j < 17; j++) {
  var row = tbl.insertRow();
  row.setAttribute("id", id.toString());
  id++;
  for (var ij = 0; ij < 36; ij++) {
    var cell = row.insertCell();
    cell.style.width = "28px";
    cell.style.height = "28px";
  }
}
body.appendChild(tbl);


function color(event) {

  var node = event.target;
  var parent = node.parentNode;

  //Probably a tbody, but we don't care as long as it is the parent
  var table = parent.parentNode;

  var column = [].slice.call(parent.childNodes).indexOf(node);
  var row = [].slice.call(table.childNodes).indexOf(parent);

  console.log(column);
  console.log(row);

  node.style.background = "black";
}
```

Edit: Since you asked how to update your array, I'll expand a bit on this. You have a reference to the DOM. If you need to track if the particular item is black, you can simply check it's style in the DOM. No need to keep a global array for this. Use `console.log( node )` if you are curious as to what you have available to you, or (better) use the [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node).

If you need the array for a different reason, you can use the `node.parentNode` and `node.childNodes` methods. Please note that the last method returns a `NodeList`; it looks like an Array, but it is actually not an array. To use array-specific functions on it, we convert it to an array with `[].slice.call( NodeList )`. Instead of `[]` you could use `Array.prototype`. I can't tell if it would behave any differently in some browsers.

Comment: But then which one did I press? Like, I also want to record that it has been pressed in an array of 612 where a black square is 1 instead of 0 but how am I supposed to find which one I pressed out?

Comment: I've updated the answer with some explanation. I would recommend reading the documentation of the things you use, to get an understanding of what is available to you.